# PHP explode string on whitespace and line break but preserved line break

Tags: php, regex

To achieve this I tried:

```
explode(" ",$string);
```

example

```
text_pressing_enter_without_space
#secondline
```

but explode is showing

```
Array [0] text_pressing_enter_without_space #secondline
```

so i tried this for both white space and line break

```
preg_split('/[\s]+/',$string)
```

example

```
$string='text_pressing_enter_without_space
#secondline';
$string=preg_split('/[\s]+/',$string);
print_r($string);
/*$final='';
foreach ($string as $g){
$final.='&nbsp;'.$g; //checking something
}*/
```

output

```
Array[0]=> text_pressing_enter_without_space Array[1]=> #secondline
```

This is doing above job but line breaks are not preserved, everything get stored on one line, so how should i preserved line break while explode string from both whitespace and line break

Comment: You may also use `preg_split('/\h+|\R/u',$string)` to account for any horizontal whitespace and any kind of line breaks. If several consecutive line breaks should result in a single array item, add `+` after `\R`: `'/\h+|\R+/u'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`$string=preg_split('/[ ]+|\n/',$string);`

It splits the string on whitespace and preserves any line breaks

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/ZIOL55678)

Comment: This won't preserve line breaks, and in fact would _consume_ `\n`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP's intentions are a bit unclear, but I guess the OP wants to preserve the line breaks in the array returned by `preg_split`, which this does.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploding using the following regex:

```
[ ]+|(?=\n)
```

This will split upon any number of *spaces*, or if the end of the line is seen.  If the end of the line is seen, it would split, but not consume, the end of line marker.

```
$string='text_pressing_enter_without_space
#secondline';
$string=preg_split('/[ ]+|(?=\n)/',$string);
print_r($string);
```

### Demo

Comment: I tried your code but output is coming >     Array ( [0] => text_pressi [1] => ng_e [2] => nter_without_space #seco [3] => ndli [4] => ne )

Comment: @Aniket Well that's not happening in the demo, which probably means that you aren't actually using my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also build your own custom parser this way:

```
function spaceBreak($str,$preserveEmptyCells=false){
    if(!is_string($str)) return [];
    $result=[];
    $chunk='';
    for($i=0,$strlen=strlen($str);$i<$strlen;$i++){
        $chunk.=$str[$i];
        if(ctype_space($str[$i])){
            if($preserveEmptyCells==false){
                if(!ctype_space($chunk)){
                    $result[]=ord($str[$i])==13||ord($str[$i])==10?$chunk:trim($chunk);
                }
            }
            else{
                $result[]=ord($str[$i])==13||ord($str[$i])==10?$chunk:trim($chunk);
            }
            $chunk='';
        }

    }
    return $result;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(spaceBreak("
 you\n can test it as 
 you
 want

 all the space will always been preserved

"));
echo '<pre>';
```

This will print to the screen

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "you
"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "can"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "it"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "as"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "you
"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "want
"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "all"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "the"
  [9]=>
  string(5) "space"
  [10]=>
  string(4) "will"
  [11]=>
  string(6) "always"
  [12]=>
  string(4) "been"
  [13]=>
  string(10) "preserved
"
}
```

As you may see all the line break are preserved but not the space.But you can preserve them too if you want by just modifying all the lines:

```
$result[]=ord($str[$i])==13||ord($str[$i])==10?$chunk:trim($chunk);
```

by

```
$result[]=$chunk;
```

in the function spaceBreak